# Vertical sidebar nav menu collapsible with one button

Tags: javascript, menu, navigation, sidebar

I'm trying to create a simple sidebar nav that works like the menu on this website -->

https://www.romereborn.org/arch-of-constantine/arch_quiz.html

Basically I'm trying to create a menu where the first click on the button opens the menu and clicking the same button closing the menu but the menu is still visible.

I started using this example on w3schools but it has two buttons rather than one. I tried editing the buttons to just have a close button that works both ways but it didn't work at all.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapse_sidebar.asp

Would anyone be able to help me or direct me to a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the openbtn button and just keep the closebtn in your HTML.

Change this in your CSS:

```
.sidebar { width: 35px }
.sidebar closebtn {right: 0px}
#main { padding-left : 40px }
```

Change your javascript to have only event with the closebtn:

```
/* Set the width of the sidebar to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0 */
let bool = false;
function closeNav() {
  bool = !bool;
  if (bool) {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.querySelector(".closebtn").innerHTML = "&times;";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "35px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    document.querySelector(".closebtn").innerHTML = "&#9776;";
  }
}
```